# Hover radius issue in CSS

Tags: html, css

The following code makes arrows with the border-radius property and on hover, it switches color. The top arrow is perfectly fine and when I hover on the border-radius it switches color. The bottom arrow, however, does not switch color unless I move away from the border-radius. Is there a way to correct this? I am assuming it has to do with the hover radius. (Border radius is the black lines that form the arrow)

```
<div class="image-arrows">
  <p><i class="up-arrow"></i></p>
  <p><i class="down-arrow"></i></p>
</div>


.image-arrows {
  width: 20px;
  height: 80px;
}

.image-arrows i {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 1.5px 1.5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3.5px;
}

.image-arrows i:hover {
  border-color: pink;
}

.up-arrow {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down-arrow {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Angatvir/pen/EedRey)

Comment: It seems to work fine for me on Vivaldi (Chrome-based). Is there any particular reason to use the border-radius property instead of simple unicode text arrow or even font-awesome or similar icon set?

Comment: In your Codepen both arrows act the same for me. The colour change will be triggered when the mouse is over the <p> element and not the border. You can see the area of this element in dev tools

Comment: Thanks guys for the help I ended up looking at font awesome.